Always getting PaymentIntent status: requires_payment_methodThe PaymentIntent requires a payment method
I am always getting this after a purchase in a Nuxt 3, stripe project: PaymentIntent status: requires_payment_methodThe PaymentIntent requires a payment method.
Here is my frontend function:
try {
    const response = await stripe.value.confirmCardPayment(secret, {
      payment_method: {
        card: card.value,
        billing_details: {
          email: email.value,
        },
      },
    });

    if (response.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
      success.value = true;
      paymentIntentId.value = response.paymentIntent.id;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error confirming card payment:', e);
  } finally {
    processingPayment.value = false;
  }
};

and here is my server function:
 try {
    paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: 97 * 100,
      currency: 'usd',
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      metadata: {
        email,
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw createError({
      statusCode: 500,
      statusMessage: 'Error creating payment intent',
    });
  }


What's the card.value mapping to? Do you get any error on console when submitting the form and running confirmCardPayment? Any error in Stripe logs?

@Lucky2501 I found out that my problem was with my zip code.... now its working fine. Thank u for ur help!
